# Facebook appid amazon ec2

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

A very specific question from a novice. I visited https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ to get a sample code for fb login. Now, the sample code requires me to create an app id to integrate a login button.

I'm using an Amazon EC2 instance.

I seem to be making a mistake, since, I dont understand where to input the amazon ec2 instance url to associate this with my fb appid.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. I just used the amazon instance url in the siteid and it worked.